# Run a javascript function of a website using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I've been wondering whether or not this is possible -

Here is a picture of Chrome's "inspect element" on this website.
[image]

Is it possible for me to run the "goCourseDetails" js function with my own parameters?

I'm using Python and selenium to try and write a script that does that for me, but I don't know how to access the JS function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: over the buildin browser developer tools. F12 -> Konsole -> print your jscode

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not helping me much though. Firstly because I want to be able to access it with python, and secondly, for example, in the screenshot I attached to the question, running the function like this will render mainForm as `undefined` and so this cannot be run like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `driver.execute_script()` to execute javascript snippet in browser.

The function `goCourseDetails` can be obtain from browser global variable `window`

```
driver.execute_script('window.goCourseDetails.call(null, arguments)',
      <department>, <degreelevel>, <course>, <detail>, <year>, <semester>
)
```

Comment: Hey, this looks like a nice solution, however when I'm doing this, I run into `Cannot set property 'target' of undefined` (so document.mainForm is probably null) is there a way to get over this?

Comment: The idea is that there's a button, that on click runs `<a href="javascript:goCourseDetails('201','1','2391','1','2019','1')">Clickme</a>` and I can't access the actual element `<a>`, and so I want to be able to "click" it, or run the function that it runs when clicked.

Comment: Can you succeed to execute `goCourseDetails('201','1','2391','1','2019','1')` in browser' console in Developer Tool.

Comment: I can run it on F12 -> Console, if that's what you meant. How does this help though?

Comment: Apparently I've done something wrong causing target to be undefined, it's working now, thanks!